# How do I set up a hosted zone on GCP?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, cdn

I have paid a contractor to take my single WP GCP instance and transfer it to a instance group> load balancer > CDN.

He tells me that over the next few days the site will go down periodically while he does this as he requires the domain.

This is problematic for me as I need my site to be live.

He says that in order to get around this, I need to create a hosted zone, then remap the IP and dns.

**QUESTION -** what does that mean and how do I do it? Can you provide a link to a blog/documentation/youtube video that shows me what to do?

I usually google these things and figure them out, but I dont understand what to google...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to move from GCP instance to an instance group in order to take advantages like GCP Cloud CDN, you must use a [GCP HTTP Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs), but an HTTP Load Balancer requires its own global public IP address, while your GCP instance can only use a regional IP address.

Taking the following as an example:

VM: 3.3.3.3
LB: 4.4.4.4
DNS: example.com

For the time being, example.com must be pointing (or solving) to 3.3.3.3 whenever a client is looking for information about that website, this is commonly handled by default by your registrar (Godaddy, Cloudflare, Google Domains, etc), what he is asking you to do would be to change that value from 3.3.3.3 to 4.4.4.4 when your website is ready.

If you want or are already handling your DNS name in GCP Cloud DNS, you must create a new zone like [this](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial#set-up-domain):

- Go to the Create a DNS zone page in the Cloud Console.
- Go to the Create a DNS zone page
- Choose Public for the Zone type.
- Enter my-new-zone for the Zone name.
- Enter a DNS name suffix for the zone using a domain name that you registered. For example, example.com.
- Under DNSSEC, keep the Off setting selected.
- Click Create. This creates a zone populated with the NS and SOA records.
- To point your registered domain name to the IP address of the hosting server, you must add an A record to your zone.
- On the Zone details page, click Add record set.
- Select A from the Resource Record Type menu.
- Under IPv4 Address, enter the external IP address for your instance.
- Click Create. This creates an A record for your zone.

But if you are handling this already with (for example) Godaddy, you must do this change on their website, then you can simply change the value from 3.3.3.3 to 4.4.4.4

Keep in mind that Google Domains (Registrar) is not the same as GCP Cloud DNS (not Registrar), they are different products and the previous procedure was intended for GCP Cloud DNS.

Given the situation you are in, I would keep the DNS value on 3.3.3.3 and your original GCP VM until everything else is ready up to do this change on your DNS configuration, your contractor can easily create a copy of your current GCP VM image, and use that to create the future instance group that will be used along with the HTTP Load Balancer without disrupting your original VM, at that point you can test the new load balancer and if everything is working as expected, then move your DNS there.

This way you would minimize any downtime you might have, but if you plan to use GCP Managed SSL certificates, those takes some time to be generated, and you will experience some downtime for this, but if you provide your own SSL certificate, you will avoid this certificate creation (because you are already providing it).